# How to get value from a ListBox 's selected item added dynamically

Tags: c#, winforms

I added dynamically a listbox on a panel in my winform. I would like to get the value from the selected item but i don't manage to do it . I have a pretty good idea why but i don't get how to do it right.

Here's my code:

```
 private void App1button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ListBox ListBoxapp = new ListBox();
            PanelLB.Controls.Add(ListBoxapp);
              string[] item = GetDesktopWindowsTitles(); 

            foreach (string app in item)
            {
                ListBoxapp.Items.Add(app);

            }
            ListBoxapp.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.InfoText;
            ListBoxapp.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(321, 135);
            ListBoxapp.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Lucida Console", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));


              if (ListBoxapp.SelectedItem != null)
                {
                MessageBox.Show("App selected is" + ListBoxapp.SelectedItem.Tostring())
                }
}
```

So this work fine it adds on my panel, i can select an item but nothing happens.

I am pretty sure it is because i can't add (after  `ListBoxapp.Font` ** )

```
ListBoxapp.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(ListBoxapp_SelectedIndexChanged);
```

it tells me `ListBoxapp_SelectedIndexChanged` doesn't exist. But considering it s added dynamically i can't do it with "priorities". I don't know hwo to add it differently. Thank you.

Comment: do you have a method named `ListBoxapp_SelectedIndexChanged` defined in your class ?

Comment: Ho, i didn't get it was a method !

Comment: check the answer below

Comment: When do you want the mbox to show? When the lbox is added, when you select some item, on another event?

Comment: I want the mbox to show after an item is selected!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define the event, subscribe to it and access the ListBox using the sender:

```
private void ListBoxapp_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     ListBox lBox = sender as ListBox;

     // do whatever you want
}
```

add this to your posted code:

```
ListBoxapp.SelectedIndexChanged += ListBoxapp_SelectedIndexChanged;
```

Comment: The issue doesn't come from that, the messagebox.show  doesn't show up

Comment: @jsls You're not subscribing to the event, so it is not firing when you changed the selected item.

Comment: I have a little issue then, i would like to have different button which add the same list BUT doesn't do the same thing (different textbox). how could i call this method (selectedIndexChanged) from my app1button void?

Comment: @jsls This is not clear. Please update your question and state exactly what you want and what you have. Example: I have 2 buttons, when i click on btn1 i want to create the ListBox and when i click on btn2 i want to do so and so. And state the expected result.

Comment: Sorry wasn't clear with myself neither, it works fine thank you !!